# Run Flash Webpage in Headless Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, flash, cucumber, headless

I am trying to run my Cucumber tests headlessly with Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 (EC2 instance so no GUI). So far my setup allows this, as the below screenshot shows:

[image: Successful Screenshot]

I have an issue when I come to a page with flash on it:

[image: Flash page]

I have restarted the EC2 instance and killed all chrome processes, still no joy.

To clarify, a test will start and chrome opens the page with flash on it and I get this message. If I then end the test and start it again I get the same problem. I guess this is not actually restarting chrome as it is a new instance each time?

So to run these tests I am using the `headless` gem [here](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) which acts as the interface to `xvfb`.

I have `Google Chrome 57.0.2987.133` and have added `libflashplayer.so` to `/opt/google/chrome/plugins`using this https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository

A few extras things I have tried include:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Is there a way to get this to work so I can render flash based sites? Do I need to enable the flash plugin each time I open chrome? I'm hoping I've missed something obvious.

#### Update

I have tried setting the `pepperflashpluginpath` when creating the Chrome profile but this is still not working:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  chrome_binary = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'

  Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_binary, "args" => ["--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/libpepflashplayer.so"] })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear... so when you do a Chrome restart (as picture #2 suggests) does Flash content then display? I mean is your real issue (a) **restart never works** because of _"I have restarted... still no joy"_ ..or is it.. (b) **how to auto-enable for always** because of _"Do I need to enable the flash plugin each time I open Chrome?"_.

Comment: Apologies for he confusion. I have added some clarification to the question but I answer to your question I think my question is how do I auto enable the flash plugin each time I spin up an instance of a chrome session, because at the moment it seems the browser knows that the plugin exists but is not enabling it. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I think you need to open chrome (manually) and go to the site and select to always allow chrome on this page.  Then close chrome and run your script.  I'm pretty sure it uses the default chrome profile when your test runs so by allowing this manually you are updating the profile yourself so your test will work.

Comment: I can't open chrome as it's all via command line, however I solved this a few hours ago, will post up my answer later so others may benefit

Comment: I am interested in doing the same.  Would greatly appreciate understanding how you solved this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Atlas1j I just posted my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

There were three key parts in getting this to work.

**Install Chromium Browser**

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser (at time this installed version 58)
```

The Chrome binary is now installed at

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

**Install Flash plugin**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/531672/how-to-install-flash-payer-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts

First go to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment the lines

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

This installs the flash plugin at

```
/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so
```

**Install Chrome Driver**

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

That's pretty much it, these were the steps that got me running this with Cucumber headless.